# How to expire our access token for testing?

Tags: oauth2, session

As mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm), the "Session timeout" setting specifies the lifetime of our access token. However, when I set it up to timeout after 15min, it does not seem to happen.

Also, the response we get when requesting the access and refresh tokens the first time generates us an access token with `@expires_in=nil` and `@expires_at=nil` despite Session timeout set as 15 min.

How can I expire the access token so to test our Refresh token process?

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke access tokens in the Connected Apps OAuth Usage section (see: [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_request_manage.htm)) - under the `User Count` link you can revoke particular user's tokens.